# Optional parameters in PointSymbolizer href

Tags: geoserver, sld, cql-filter, cql

I am trying to build a dynamic url for a PointSymbolizer:

```
/api/icons?foo=${strUrlEncode("foo")}&bar=${strUrlEncode("bar")}
```

The problem I am running into is that the `strUrlEncode` will return null if the `"foo"` property is `null`.  When that happens I get the following exception:

```
DEBUG [function.string] - Failed to concatenate string in Concatenate function
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.net.URLEncoder.encode(URLEncoder.java:204)
    at org.geotools.filter.function.string.URLEncodeFunction.evaluate(URLEncodeFunction.java:87)
    at org.geotools.filter.expression.ExpressionAbstract.evaluate(ExpressionAbstract.java:45)
    at org.geotools.filter.function.string.ConcatenateFunction.evaluate(ConcatenateFunction.java:66)
    at org.geotools.filter.expression.ExpressionAbstract.evaluate(ExpressionAbstract.java:45)
```

I imagine that is happening because the result of my first `strUrlEncode` (which is null) is being concatenated to the second parameter.

Is there any way I can provide a default non-null value in a case where `foo` is `null` to avoid the NPE?

Comment: Why not check the value before you pass it to PointSymbolizer?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by check it first.  If you are talking about a rule, that becomes problematic when there is more than 2 query params.  I would have to provide rules for each enumeration ie if (foo & bar & third) or if(foo &bar) or if(foo & third) and so on.  So even with just 3 query params the logic is a bit "heavy"

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the java function `URLEncoder.encode()` doesn't handle null arguments and the GeoTools function is not checking if the argument is null. You need to add a check before [line 87](https://github.com/geotools/geotools/blob/master/modules/library/main/src/main/java/org/geotools/filter/function/string/URLEncodeFunction.java#L87) and return an empty string or "null" if the argument is null.

As always [pull requests with a test](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/developer/procedures/contribute.html) case are welcome.